# Can't delete dynamically allocated multidimensional array

Tags: c++, dynamic, multidimensional-array, delete-operator

I can't delete the dynamically generated arrays. There is how I create them:

```
template <typename T>
T **AllocateDynamic2DArray(int nRows, int nCols){
      T **dynamicArray;

      dynamicArray = new T*[nRows];
      for( int i = 0 ; i < nRows ; i++ ){
        dynamicArray[i] = new T[nCols];
        for ( int j=0; j<nCols;j++){
                dynamicArray[i][j]= 0;
            }
        }
      return dynamicArray;
}
```

And I initialize a 2D array using:

```
long double** h = AllocateDynamic2DArray<long double>(KrylovDim+1,KrylovDim);
```

I can't delete it. Here are the variations that I've tried:

```
delete[] h;
```

and it gives the error: "cannot delete objects that are not pointers" when I apply this:

```
   for (int qq=0; qq < KrylovDim+1; qq++){
        for (int ww=0; ww < KrylovDim; ww++){
            delete [] h[qq][ww];
        }
        delete [] h[qq];
    }
```

Is there any way for a clean delete? I'm using visual studio 2010 if it helps.

Comment: Easy way to figure this out: you must have exactly one (not more, not fewer) `delete`, for every `new`. In your allocation, you invoke `new`  `1+nRows` times. How many times do you invoke `delete`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int qq=0; qq < KrylovDim + 1; qq++)
{
    delete [] h[qq];
}
delete [] h;
```

So basically you are doing the reverse of the allocation process

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < nRows ; i++ ){
    dynamicArray[i] = new T[nCols]; // Instead of allocating now delete !
```

Comment: @Emre np. Sorry for the multiple edits but I was juggling somethings at the same time :)

Comment: R: so you start deleting by the outermost dimension? if it was a 4D array, we would have 3 loops to delete and 1 delete[] h. cool.

Comment: @Emre yup... basically just do the exact reverse of the allocation process.