# How to free 2D struct with 2D array as a attribute

Tags: c, memory, struct, malloc, free

I have defined struct as

```
struct global_data
{
double el[6][6];
}**C;
```

And allocated memory as

```
C = (struct global_data **) malloc(20*sizeof(struct     global_data *));

for(i=0;i<=20;i++)
{
C[i]=(struct global_data *) malloc(sizeof(struct global_data)*20);
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how to free this memory allocated here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836171/c-cant-delete-dynamically-allocated-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call free() for every malloc you made

```
for(int i=0;i<20;i++) 
{
    free( C[i] ) ;
}
free( C ) ;
```

Also your for loop is incorrect, you make 21 iterations instead of 20, should be:

```
for(i=0;i<20;i++)
{
    C[i]=(struct global_data *) malloc(sizeof(struct global_data)*20);
}
```